# How do I switch this MATLAB loop to a Python loop

Tags: python, list, matlab, compare, conditional-statements

So I have a challenge in my hand that I am trying to accomplish. I have a matlab code that works fine homever, I want to write the same code in python. Homever I don't get the same results.

I have tried using a different for loop than the one in matlab. Although these should give the same results I am fail at some point in the loop, although I couldn't figure out where the mistake was.

```
for ii = 1:100 #matlab code
healthy=2*randn(100,1000)+5;
patient=2*randn(100,1000)+7;
threshold=mu_healthy-sd_healthy:0.1:mu_patient+sd_patient;
for i=1:length(threshold)
TP(i)=sum(patient>=threshold(i));
FP(i)=sum(healthy>=threshold(i));
TN(i)=sum(healthy<threshold(i));
FN(i)=sum(patient<threshold(i));
end
FPR(ii,:)=FP/1000;
TPR(ii,:)=TP/1000;

def appending(): #python code 
    for n in range(0,50):
        for x in range(0,1000):
            for a in range(0,61):
                if Apatient[x,n]>=newthreshold[a]:
                    TP[a].append(Apatient[x,n])
                elif Ahealthy[x,n]>=newthreshold[a]:
                    FP.append(Ahealthy[x,n])
                elif Apatient[x,n]<newthreshold[a]:
                    TN.append(Apatient[x,n])
                elif Ahealthy[x,n]<newthreshold[a]:
                    FN.append(Ahealthy[x,n])
```

If you can run this in matlab, you will see FN,TN values with 61 values in each column. I want the same to happen in my loop as well,homever I get lots of elements if I run this code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following MATLAB script, tried translation.

```
import numpy as np

mu_healthy = 5
sd_healthy = 2
mu_patient = 7
sd_patient = 2
threshold = np.arange(mu_healthy-sd_healthy, mu_patient+sd_patient+0.1, 0.1)
L = len(threshold)

TP = np.zeros([L,1])
FP = np.zeros([L,1])
TN = np.zeros([L,1])
FN = np.zeros([L,1])
FPR = np.zeros([100,L])
TPR = np.zeros([100,L])

for ii in range(0,100):
    healthy = sd_healthy*np.random.normal(mu_healthy,1,[100,1000])
    patient = sd_patient*np.random.normal(mu_patient,1,[100,1000])


    for i in range(0, L):
        TP[i] = np.sum(patient>=threshold[i])
        FP[i] = np.sum(healthy>=threshold[i])
        TN[i] = np.sum(healthy<threshold[i])
        FN[i] = np.sum(patient<threshold[i])


    FPR[ii,:] = FP[:,0]
    TPR[ii,:] = TP[:,0]

FPR = FPR/1000
TPR = TPR/1000
```